# Unicode converted text isn't shown properly in MS-Word

Tags: unicode, ms-word

In a mapping editor, the display is correct after the **legacy to unicode conversion** for **DEVANAGARI** text shown using a unicode font (Arial Unicode MS). However, in **MS-WORD**, the **display isn't as expected** for the same unicode text in the unicode font (Arial Unicode MS) or any other Devanagari unicode fonts. The expected sequence of unicodes are provided as per the documentation. The sequence can be seen on the left-hand side table.

[image]
Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your map have to insert the zero_width_joiner? The halant (virama) by itself is enough to get the half-consonant (for some combinations) and in particular, it may be that Word is using the presence of the ZWJ to keep them separate.

If getting rid of the ZWJ doesn't help, another possibility is that Word may be treating the individual characters of the text string as individual "runs" of text.

If those first 4 characters are not in a single run, this can happen.

[aside: the way to tell if it's being treated as a single run, is to save the document as an xml file and then open it with something like notepad++ and look at the xml "w:t" element (IIRC) associated with these characters. If they're all in separate w:t elements, it means they're in separate runs. In that case, you might need to copy the text from Word to some other tool (e.g. Notepad++) and then copy it from there and paste it back in Word -- that might cause it to be imported into Word in a single run.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bob! Removing the ZWJ makes it work. Additional information that you given is great. In fact, reading your KrutiDev010.map has helped me a lot.